# how to change the name of lists to unique

Tags: r

I have a list like this

a toy data like this

```
ltd <- list(structure(list(Abund = c("BROS", "KIS", "TTHS", 
"MKS"), `Value: F111: cold, Sample1` = c("1.274e7", "", 
"", "2.301e7"), `Value: F111: warm, Sample1` = c("", "", 
"", "")), .Names = c("Abund", "Value: F111: cold, Sample1", 
"Value: F111: warm, Sample1"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(Abund = c("BROS", "TMS", "KIS", 
    "HERS"), `Value: F216: cold, Sample2` = c("1.670e6", 
    "4.115e7", "", "1.302e7"), `Value: F216: warm, Sample2` = c("", 
    "2.766e7", "", "1.396e7")), .Names = c("Abund", "Value: F216: cold, Sample2", 
    "Value: F216: warm, Sample2"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(Abund = c("BROS", "TMS", "KIS", 
    "HERS"), `Value: F655: cold, Sample3` = c("7.074e4", 
    "1.038e7", "", "7.380e5"), `Value: F655: warm, Sample3` = c("", 
    "6.874e6", "", "7.029e5")), .Names = c("Abund", "Value: F655: cold, Sample3", 
    "Value: F655: warm, Sample3"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame"))  



List of 5000
     $ :'data.frame':   397 obs. of  3 variables:
      ..$ Abund                      : chr [1:363] "TTT" "MMM" "GTR" "NLM" ...
      ..$ Value: F111: Warm, Sample1: chr [1:363] "1.274e7" "" "" "2.301e7" ...
      ..$ Value: F111: Cold, Sample1: chr [1:363] "" "" "" "" ...
     $ :'data.frame':   673 obs. of  3 variables:
      ..$ Abund                      : chr [1:673] "MGL" "KKK" "LFT" "NKL" ...
      ..$ Value: F216: Warm, Sample2: chr [1:673] "1.670e6" "4.115e7" "" "1.302e7" ...
      ..$ Value: F216: Cold, Sample2: chr [1:673] "" "2.766e7" "" "1.396e7" ...
     $ :'data.frame':   779 obs. of  3 variables:
      ..$ Abund                      : chr [1:779] "TTLS" "KIS" "KISA" "LISU" ...
      ..$ Value: F655: Warm, Sample3: chr [1:779] "7.074e4" "1.038e7" "" "7.380e5" ...
      ..$ Value: F655: Cold, Sample3: chr [1:779] "" "6.874e6" "" "7.029e5" ...
     $ :'data.frame':   387 obs. of  3 variables:
      ..$ Abund                     : chr [1:387] "BRO" "BIA" "KIA" "TTHS" ...
      ..$ Value: F57: Warm, Sample4: chr [1:387] "6.910e6" "" "2.435e7" "3.924e6" ...
      ..$ Value: F57: Cold, Sample4: chr [1:387] "5.009e6" "" "" "3.624e6" ...
     $ :'data.frame':   543 obs. of  3 variables:
```

I want to give unique names to the abund starting from 1 to whatever it has , so the output should look like

So a disire output looks like below. I have to just write blah blah that this web allow me to post my question otherwise it does not allow

```
  List of 5000
         $ :'data.frame':   397 obs. of  3 variables:
          ..$ Abund1                      : chr [1:363] "TTT" "MMM" "GTR" "NLM" ...
          ..$ Value: F111: Warm, Sample1: chr [1:363] "1.274e7" "" "" "2.301e7" ...
          ..$ Value: F111: Cold, Sample1: chr [1:363] "" "" "" "" ...
         $ :'data.frame':   673 obs. of  3 variables:
          ..$ Abund2                      : chr [1:673] "MGL" "KKK" "LFT" "NKL" ...
          ..$ Value: F216: Warm, Sample2: chr [1:673] "1.670e6" "4.115e7" "" "1.302e7" ...
          ..$ Value: F216: Cold, Sample2: chr [1:673] "" "2.766e7" "" "1.396e7" ...
         $ :'data.frame':   779 obs. of  3 variables:
          ..$ Abund3                      : chr [1:779] "TTLS" "KIS" "KISA" "LISU" ...
          ..$ Value: F655: Warm, Sample3: chr [1:779] "7.074e4" "1.038e7" "" "7.380e5" ...
          ..$ Value: F655: Cold, Sample3: chr [1:779] "" "6.874e6" "" "7.029e5" ...
         $ :'data.frame':   387 obs. of  3 variables:
          ..$ Abund4                     : chr [1:387] "BRO" "BIA" "KIA" "TTHS" ...
          ..$ Value: F57: Warm, Sample4: chr [1:387] "6.910e6" "" "2.435e7" "3.924e6" ...
          ..$ Value: F57: Cold, Sample4: chr [1:387] "5.009e6" "" "" "3.624e6" ...
```

Comment: [`make.unique`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.unique.html) or [`make.names(...,unique=TRUE)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html).

Comment: @r2evans what about the ording ? it is not really unique unique, they take numbers from the other part of the name, please look at it carefully

Comment: Okay. The data doesn't make a lot of sense to me, please provide something *usable*; typically this means using `dput(head(x,n=10))` or similar, but that won't work as well here because of the depth of your data. I suggest you do something like `dput(lapply(x[1:3], head, n=4))` and then from that tell us what you expect the output to be. What other code have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide a toy example of your data. Otherwise, we'll be stuck guessing. working with nebulous data structures is quite frustrating.

Comment: @lmo I pasted it above

Comment: @r2evans I pasted it above

Comment: That's what I suspected. Your column names are certainly non-standard, and trying to use them in a `data.frame` can be done but can be difficult (and I'm not convinced all tools will be able to work around them). I suggest first that you come up with simpler names for each element. Second, *"so that I can convert it to a data frame"* after making each nested frame's columns' names *unique* makes no sense to me; my assumption is that you mean to combine them so that instead of a list of data.frames, you have one frame. This won't work if you uniqify the names. *Please provide expected output.*

Comment: As a side note, it looks like part of the problem is the data import method used to form this structure. If you have any control over it, I suggest you work on that end in addition to or instead of this side of things. (If you do have control yet don't have the time, so be it, but importing right the first time can preclude the need to fix many broken components later.)

Comment: @r2evans I changed my question. i just want to add number to the first name from 1 to whatever there is . please look at the desire output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve a problem like this, instead of attacking the big problem up front, it's best to solve one piece of it at a time. If we look at just one frame from your list, I'll call it `x`:

```
x <- structure(list(Abund = c("BROS", "KIS", "TTHS", 
"MKS"), `Value: F111: cold, Sample1` = c("1.274e7", "", 
"", "2.301e7"), `Value: F111: warm, Sample1` = c("", "", 
"", "")), .Names = c("Abund", "Value: F111: cold, Sample1", 
"Value: F111: warm, Sample1"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
str(x)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Abund111                  : chr  "BROS" "KIS" "TTHS" "MKS"
#  $ Value: F111: cold, Sample1: chr  "1.274e7" "" "" "2.301e7"
#  $ Value: F111: warm, Sample1: chr  "" "" "" ""
```

You had originally wanted to append the number after the "F" in the other column names. I'll attack that first, and then if you really want it, I'll also do the "append an incrementing number" thing.

### F-number

Write a function that finds the "F" number within the second column name and appends it to the first column name. (I'm wondering if there are more diverse patterns of headers in your full dataset; I'm confident that the regex we use here can easily be manipulated to handle them, given enough varying samples.)

```
somefunc <- function(x) {
  cn2 <- colnames(x)[2]
  Fnum <- gsub(".*F([0-9]+).*", "\\1", cn2)
  colnames(x)[1] <- paste0(colnames(x)[1], Fnum)
  x
}
```

A brief explanation:

- `colnames(x)[2]` just retrieves the second one; I'm assuming that we can base everything on the presence and makeup of this second column
- `gsub(".*F([0-9]+).*", "\\1", cn2)` extracts just the numbers after "F"; for the record, if it weren't for the `Sample`, we might be able to discard any non-number, but I chose being safe here.

  - `.*` matches zero or more "anything" characters; sandwiching the rest with this on both sides of our group is essentially discarding all but the number we want
  - `F` the literal "F"
  - `(...)` this is a group, saved for later (referenced with the `\\1` in the replacement string, the second argument to `gsub`)
  - `[0-9]+` accepts anything within the brackets, which can be literals (`[acf]` matches the three letters) or a range (`[0-9A-F]` matches any digit and any letters between A and F); the `+` makes it "one or more" (contrasting with the `*` before which is zero or more)
- `colnames(x)[1] <- ...` reassign the first column name

The work on the "single frame":

```
str( somefunc(x) )
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Abund111                  : chr  "BROS" "KIS" "TTHS" "MKS"
#  $ Value: F111: cold, Sample1: chr  "1.274e7" "" "" "2.301e7"
#  $ Value: F111: warm, Sample1: chr  "" "" "" ""
```

So now the question is how to apply this function that operates on one frame across a list of frames. `lapply` to the rescue:

```
str(lapply(ltd, somefunc))
# List of 3
#  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Abund111                  : chr [1:4] "BROS" "KIS" "TTHS" "MKS"
#   ..$ Value: F111: cold, Sample1: chr [1:4] "1.274e7" "" "" "2.301e7"
#   ..$ Value: F111: warm, Sample1: chr [1:4] "" "" "" ""
#  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Abund216                  : chr [1:4] "BROS" "TMS" "KIS" "HERS"
#   ..$ Value: F216: cold, Sample2: chr [1:4] "1.670e6" "4.115e7" "" "1.302e7"
#   ..$ Value: F216: warm, Sample2: chr [1:4] "" "2.766e7" "" "1.396e7"
#  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Abund655                  : chr [1:4] "BROS" "TMS" "KIS" "HERS"
#   ..$ Value: F655: cold, Sample3: chr [1:4] "7.074e4" "1.038e7" "" "7.380e5"
#   ..$ Value: F655: warm, Sample3: chr [1:4] "" "6.874e6" "" "7.029e5"
```

### Incrementing number

This is both easier and harder. First, we attack the small problem:

```
otherfunc <- function(x, num) {
  colnames(x)[1] <- paste0(colnames(x)[1], num)
  x
}
```

Pretty straight forward. But we cannot use `lapply`: all it does it accept a single argument, so it will not know what to do for the number. One might be tempted to brute-force things with a tracking variable somewhere (global? please no), but it might be interesting to know that there is a variant of the "apply" functions that operates differently: `mapply` takes one or more lists, and "zips" them together. For example:

```
myfunc <- c
mapply(myfunc, 1:3, 4:6, 7:9, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 4 7
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 5 8
# [[3]]
# [1] 3 6 9
```

We started with three (could have been more) independent vectors (could have been lists, typically are), and took the first value from each and passed them to the function. So this is effectively like:

```
list(myfunc(1, 4, 7), mufunc(2, 5, 8), myfunc(3, 6, 9))
```

Ok, so realizing that we want to "zip" together each frame with `ltd` with a number along a sequence, those numbers are easily generated with:

```
seq_along(ltd)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

(This is considered better than `1:length(ltd)`, since the latter will not behave correctly if the length is 0 ... try `1:length(list())` versus `seq_along(list())`.)

Okay, so let's use this new trick:

```
str(mapply(otherfunc, ltd, seq_along(ltd), SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
# List of 3
#  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Abund1                    : chr [1:4] "BROS" "KIS" "TTHS" "MKS"
#   ..$ Value: F111: cold, Sample1: chr [1:4] "1.274e7" "" "" "2.301e7"
#   ..$ Value: F111: warm, Sample1: chr [1:4] "" "" "" ""
#  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Abund2                    : chr [1:4] "BROS" "TMS" "KIS" "HERS"
#   ..$ Value: F216: cold, Sample2: chr [1:4] "1.670e6" "4.115e7" "" "1.302e7"
#   ..$ Value: F216: warm, Sample2: chr [1:4] "" "2.766e7" "" "1.396e7"
#  $ :'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Abund3                    : chr [1:4] "BROS" "TMS" "KIS" "HERS"
#   ..$ Value: F655: cold, Sample3: chr [1:4] "7.074e4" "1.038e7" "" "7.380e5"
#   ..$ Value: F655: warm, Sample3: chr [1:4] "" "6.874e6" "" "7.029e5"
```

It should be noted that `mapply`, just like `sapply`, will by default try to simplify things; I find it hard to trust that it always do what I want, so I typically turn off this simplification. There are times for it, yes, here is not that time. The `apply` functions (including `Reduce`) are typically very hard to learn to use when thinking in a linear/iterative methodology, but they can be very useful in times like these.

Comment: you have spent so much time on this. I did not check your results but I appreciate your help VERYYYYY MUCH. I liked and accepted your answer THANK you

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can do it this way :

```
ltd2 <- Map(function(x,y) {names(x)[1] <- paste0(names(x)[1],y);x},ltd,seq(ltd))
str(ltd2)
# List of 3
# $ :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Abund1                    : chr [1:4] "BROS" "KIS" "TTHS" "MKS"
# ..$ Value: F111: cold, Sample1: chr [1:4] "1.274e7" "" "" "2.301e7"
# ..$ Value: F111: warm, Sample1: chr [1:4] "" "" "" ""
# $ :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Abund2                    : chr [1:4] "BROS" "TMS" "KIS" "HERS"
# ..$ Value: F216: cold, Sample2: chr [1:4] "1.670e6" "4.115e7" "" "1.302e7"
# ..$ Value: F216: warm, Sample2: chr [1:4] "" "2.766e7" "" "1.396e7"
# $ :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   ..$ Abund3                    : chr [1:4] "BROS" "TMS" "KIS" "HERS"
# ..$ Value: F655: cold, Sample3: chr [1:4] "7.074e4" "1.038e7" "" "7.380e5"
# ..$ Value: F655: warm, Sample3: chr [1:4] "" "6.874e6" "" "7.029e5"
```

But I would use `purrr::imap` and `dplyr::rename_at` for same result:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
ltd3 <- imap(ltd,~rename_at(.,1,paste0,.y))
```

Comment: how would you comvert that to a data frame ? simply using as.data.frame ?

Comment: your desired output as stated on question was a list, what kind of data.frame would you like as an output ?

Comment: I liked your answer just to appreciate your time. I will ask a question in few minutes

Comment: I was also confused by your previous question of converting to a data.frame but showing a list as your intended output. Judging by your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466882/how-can-i-combine-all-lists-and-make-a-unique-names), I am really confused why you wanted to uniquify your names when your desired output does not use the uniqueness.

Comment: same here it's not really clear why you want to get rid of numbers in your new question when in this question you wanted to add them, i suspect there might be a common simple solution to all pieces of data wrangling you're stitching together